# How to get thumbnail of Facebook user's picture, by messenger user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I have a messenger bot, that receives a user id, which I can then use to send a request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{user_id}?access_token={token} that returns an object like this:

```
{
   "first_name": {name},
   "last_name": {surname},
   "profile_pic": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/{stuff}.jpg?oh={stuff}&oe={stuff}",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "timezone": 3,
   "gender": "male",
   "id": {user_id}
}
```

The profile_pic field contains a url to the full sized profile picture. How do I get a thumbnail?

Requesting
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{user_id}/picture does not work for this ID.So I can't use the parameters for that.

If I request
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{user_id}?fields=profile_pic.width(40).height(40).as(picture_small) the alias works, but the link is still to a full sized picture.

Comment: why not just programmatically resize the image to what you want?

Comment: I'd have to either do it on every request, which is very CPU intensive, or store the thumbnails, which takes space and I'm not even sure if that's legal under EU personal data laws.